# Run program on raspbian buster LXDE startup

Tags: python, boot, lxde

I know this question has been asked before, but the methods referenced are not working for me. Currently I have done this: 
`sudo nano /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart` and added the line `@python3 /home/pi/Desktop/filename.py` I tried with sudo but for some reason one of my python modules fails to import when I use sudo. Is there something wrong with my commands? Or is there an alternative way to run this python GUI script on startup?

Comment: Are you logging on as root?

Comment: @Milliways Yes, why?

Comment: Mixing root invocations with scripts in `/home/pi` is probably a bad idea with python as you are libel to end up with modules installed in `/home/pi` which *won't* be found when the script is invoked as root.

Comment: Use a systemd unit file to run your script on startup.